# Incorrect output from overloaded [] function

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, subscript

The spec says that the function must return the row of the matrix specified by the "row number" in []

Class Definition:

```
class Matrix
{
 public:

 //functions taken out 

 private:
  double ** matrix; // the matrix array
  unsigned rows; // # rows
  unsigned cols; // # columns
};
```

The brief main:

```
 cout << "Test []: " << endl;
  try {
   Matrix row = m0[0]; //**m0 is Matrix m0(1,1); where the constructor creates the appropriate array** 
    cout << row << endl;
    row = m0[1];
    cout << row << endl;
    row = m0[100];  // should throw an exception
  } catch (const char * err) {
    cout << err << endl;
  }
```

The Function implementation:

```
 double& Matrix::operator [](const unsigned int &sub)
{   
     if( sub >= rows)
    {
        const char * error = "Error: invalid row index";
        throw error;

    } else
        {       
            return *matrix[sub];

        }


}
```

Overloaded << operator for display:

```
//This is working for my other displays so this shouldn't be the problem
ostream &operator << (ostream &ostrm, const Matrix &obj)
{
    //Loop through to display
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < obj.rows; i++)
    {       
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j< obj.cols; j++)
        {
            ostrm << setw(10)  << setprecision(3) << obj.matrix[i][j]; 
        }

        ostrm << endl;
    }

    return ostrm;
}
```

Overloaded = operator:

```
//Again this works for everything else 
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix &rhs)
{
    //Copy Rows and Cols
    rows = rhs.rows;
    cols = rhs.cols;

    //If statement to check for self assignment
    if(&rhs == this)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    else 
    {
        delete [] matrix;

        matrix = new double*[rows]; //Allocate Dynamic Array

        //Deep copy elements by looping and copying each element
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            matrix[i] = new double[cols];
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                matrix[i][j] = rhs.matrix[i][j];
            }

        }

        return *this;

    }


}
```

My Output:

```
Test []: 


Error: invalid row index
```

Expected Output:

```
Test []: 
      17.2        -3      -0.5         6

       8.2         4         3         1

Error: invalid row index
```

I am uncertain as to why the rows are not displaying or possibly not even being stored.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the `Matrix` class definition. For example, what is `matrix`? How is it declared? How is it initialized? Preferably please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: It's still not a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `m0`? Is it a `Matrix` object? How could you then do `Matrix row = m0[0]` when the `operator[]` function returns a reference to a *single `double` value*? What constructors do you have for `Matrix`? Do your move- or copy-constructors work as they should?

Comment: Also, do you follow [the rules of three or five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? Perhaps you should stop using pointers, and start using `std::vector` instead, and then follow [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero) instead?

Comment: Matrix classes take a jolly large amount of time to build. Yours is littered with bugs and design flaws. Why not use BLAS, available from the boost distribution?

Comment: Bugs? Design Flaws? I can't fix something if I don't know it's wrong? It's a varsity assignment, it has to be implemented this..

Answer (score 0):

Aside comment: your assignment operator is leaking memory: you delete `matrix`, but you need to delete also the individual rows (using the original value of rows)

`for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  delete[] matrix[i];`

Your `operator[]` should return a `double[]` or `double *`, not a `double` - you want to return a whole row, not a single value.

Your "test []" code should not even compile... `Matrix row = m0[0];` assigns a `double` to a `Matrix` object.

Etc.

Bottom line: just use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

Comment: So if I make my return type double*  what exactly should I return, because I am still getting the same error? Thank you for a decent answer! Much appreciated

Comment: You have to make some choices for `operator[]`
  - it can return a proxy object to the data in the original Matrix: this is what a `double *` effectively does, but you would wrap it in an object that knows the size of the row, and has operators to interact with the Matrix;
  - it can return a copy of the data, wrapped in a Row object;
  - it can return a copy of the data, wrapped in a Nx1 Matrix object.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but we haven't covered proxy objects or the wrap part. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: All these types can implement interaction with a Matrix object, other objects of the same type, or scalars, and they can implement `operator<<`. So it is mostly a matter of taste, and of how you are going to use your Matrix class.

Comment: The Matrix class is stupidly simple. It's just a first year varsity assignment (This is why I can't use Eigen, we have to struggle through it). It literally just has to return the row  and then the operator<< handles it. I also tried creating a new array with only one row and copying the elements into it, but that also didn't help

Comment: Then you should probably implement a `Row` class, and let `Matrix::operator[]` return one of them by value (just copy the elements of the row into the `Row` object).
And you can implement `Row::operator<<` to do what you want.

If it helps debugging, you could implement `Matrix::operator<<` to print all the rows, one at a time, and make sure tha works first.

Answer (score 0):

The first line is wrong.
operator[] is returning a double. You assign it to a Matrix. The Matrix is initialized with one value. You've taken out your Constructors. Which one is called? I assume, the called constructor initializes the rows and cols members with zero. When they're zero, the output stream operator does nothing.

Comment: Even if the called Constructor is not initializing the members, there's still a possibility that they are zero.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution that worked for my question. Below is what I implemented in case someone else has a similar problem.

```
Matrix temp(1, cols); //Calls my constructor here

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {   

            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                temp.matrix[i][j] = matrix[sub][j]; //Accessed temp's matrix and assigned it with what is in the matrix that called the function
            }


        }

        return temp;
```

Thank you to everyone who helped and added some input. Much appreciated